# android from activity D to B intent flag

Tags: android

i'm a new android developer.now i want to develop an app and implement a situation.
 i have 4 activity,Activity **A->B->C->D**. 
i want from D to B,finish C and resume B(if exist,just execute on-resume).
now i used following flags :

```
FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
```

but this two flags will cause activity to execute onCreate method.
i have a lot of  things to do in oncreate method ,so i just want to resume the Activity B.

many thanks!

**Update:**
now i using follow code In Activity D(go to Activity B),it looks very well.any other better idea？

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(this,ActivityB.class);
mIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(mIntent);
```

Comment: please explain your transition between activities clearly. when you want to move and where you want to move

Comment: Finish your activity C when you create D from C. Since the flow is from B-> C->D, after the process in D onResume() of activity B will automatically  call.

Comment: @ZahanSafallwa open activity A，open activity B(click button under activity A ) ...    A->B->C->D. when Activity D has been open. i want back to B ,destroy C and resume B.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to navigate from D to B all the time, you can finish C while navigating to D.

in your C :

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, D.class);
finish();
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: it doesnt resume B. It starts from onCreate.

Comment: @ZahanSafallwa and how do you know that?

Comment: oh sorry misunderstanding. took decision too early. up voted

Comment: @ZahanSafallwa finish C before start D,this is a good idea,but i don't want to this, sometimes D can back to C.now i use 'Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP' ,it looks good. i have updated code.

Answer (score 0):

first dont finish activities on going to another activity and also remove 
FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

and use
 android:launchMode="singleInstance"

in your manifest file with B activity

```
<activity name="B.class"
 android:launchMode="singleInstance"
/>
```

Comment: this will keep activity B single but C will always be there.... it doesnt solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can call startAcivityForResult() function to change activity and check the intent data to stop/continue . It's so easy and you can handle every activity by this .

Comment: it can resolve this problem,but i don't think this is not a better solution. if we want to back to A from D, i will change too many places.

Answer (score 0):

Better you use startactivityforresult
your requirement "i want from D to B,finish C and resume B(if exist,just execute on-resume)."

for this when calling D from C use

```
startactivityforresult(intent,requestCode)
```

now when you done with D just call `setResult(ResultOK)`

and handle this result onActivityResult of C activity and finish the c activity there

here automaticaly your B activity onresume is called

any further query please notify me 
more about startactivityforresult `http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/basics/intents/result.html
also you can try @Kamalone comment that at time of calling D just finish C if the only requirement is finishing C or go for startactivityforresult if you want to handle some result

Comment: i have a lot of place want to this.so i want  a simple solution just change a little class.but thanks Pavan.